# Django reversing of database contents in HTML

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Hopefully a simple question for you here. So I have a sort of image library I list out in a page as rows. Initially it lists out from oldest to newest. I prefer newest to oldest. Solved it by reversing the query in the for loop. Like so:

```
{% for image in gallery reversed %}
```

My question is, is there a better way to do it? Perhaps in the views.py file? The above seems rather...slapped on or something. I know it involves "reverse()", but I don't know how to implement it. Here's the section in views.py:

```
def user_profile(request):
    context = {}
    populateContext(request, context)
    user_details = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    context.update(user_details=user_details)


    """ blah blah """


    context.update(gallery=ImageDoc.objects.only('thumbfile').filter(user_id=request.user.id))
    return render(request, 'register/profile.html', context)
```

It should be in the second-last line there, as that's where the contents are stored into the "context" dictionary.

Comment: How do you define "oldest"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view currently has no ordering at all, it just appears to show some level of ordering since quite often values are retrieved in the order they are added to the database.

You can use [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#order-by), and by starting the field with a `-` it will be in reverse order

Therefore, to achieve the same output as you're currently seeing you need

```
ImageDoc.objects.only('thumbfile').filter(user_id=request.user.id).order_by('-id')
```